# VB2010 reading menu items in tool strip sub menu

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu, menu

SQL Server/VB2010 newbie.  Fighting the learning curve on two fronts.

I am creating a UI in VB2010 to a SQL Server database that will allow users to edit tables in the database. Since the tables in the database may change (new ones added, or obsolete ones deleted) as the project develops, the table names are dynamically added to the sub menu, as shown in the screen cap below:

[image: Screen Cap]

Then I use the AddHandler function to run the click event sub. That works fine, but what I need to do is grab the actual text of the submenu item ("VehicleList", "Maintenance", etc.) to use in the SQL SELECT string to open the selected table in the database, like so:

```
"SELECT * from [selected_menu_item] WHERE yada, yada"
```

I've scoured the internet looking for this, but if it's there, I can't find it. Tried many ways, but I either get the top menu item ("Table") or the last item on the list, or sometimes just a blank line.

Preferable would be to get the actual names, but even if there was an index value, I could use that to reference an array of the table names.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use the "ByVal e As ToolStripItemClickedArgs" argument in the handler, like this:

```
 Private Sub MenuItem_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs)

    Debug.WriteLine(e.ClickedItem.Text)

End Sub
```

Found this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemclickedeventargs.clickeditem.aspx

It works exactly as I need it to!